# Is a small tube of Gorilla glue permitted in hand luggage on board plane?

Tags: aircraft

Can I take a small tube of Gorilla Glue on board a plane in my hand luggage?

Answer (score 1):

Most countries (USA included) have the so called 3-1-1 liquid rule: travel-sized containers that are 3.4 ounces (100 milliliters) or less per item, these items in a quart sized bag, one bag per customer.

As far as I can see, you can buy 2oz of Gorilla Glue so that should be OK.

Your other possible problem is -- it is flammable. The rule is:

> Gasoline, gas torches, lighter fluid, cooking fuel, other types of flammable liquid fuel, flammable paints, paint thinner, turpentine, aerosols (exceptions for personal care items, toiletries, or medically related items).

at this point I'd say it's anyone's guess whether they will let it through or not. It definitely goes into the liquid baggie and be prepared to throw it away. My speculation is they won't catch it or know it's flammable but who knows.

Comment: Most security personal would know that elephant / super glues are flammable.  But whether they would spot it amongst your other toiletries in the plastic bag is another question.